# Change controller redirect url with plugin Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I have redirect from controller and I want to change that redirect url inside plugin.

This is how it looks currently.

Controller:

```
        ...
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Invitation to corporate account accepted.'));
        $this->corporateManagement->setCorporateSessionVars($customer->getId());

        return $this->_redirect($this->_url->getUrl('corporate/users'));
```

And I want to change that redirect to redirect to another url (must be with plugin). This is how I tried to achieve this with plugin and plugin works $result is changed but the user is still redirected to url inside controller and not the one from plugin.

Plugin:

```
    public function afterExecute(\Iways\Corporate\Controller\Invitation\Accept $subject, $result)
    {
        $corporateBranding = $this->corporateBrandingManagement->getCorporateBranding();

        if ($corporateBranding && $corporateBranding->getStoreGroupId()) {
            $storeGroup = $this->storeManager->getGroup($corporateBranding->getStoreGroupId());
            $store = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeGroup->getDefaultStoreId());
            $redirectUrl = $store->getBaseUrl().'corporate/users';
            $result = $this->redirect->getRedirect($redirectUrl);
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

**Important note:** All properties and methods are working correctly, $result is populated with another redirect and $result is returned but user is redirected to the url from controller and not the one from plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can try to use `around` instead `after`. In the around  and dont return $proceed() just return the value that you use in your plugin.

I didn't test this but i believe it should work.

```
    public function aroundExecute(\Iways\Corporate\Controller\Invitation\Accept $subject, $proceed)
    {
        $proceed();
        $corporateBranding = $this->corporateBrandingManagement->getCorporateBranding();

        if ($corporateBranding && $corporateBranding->getStoreGroupId()) {
            $storeGroup = $this->storeManager->getGroup($corporateBranding->getStoreGroupId());
            $store = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeGroup->getDefaultStoreId());
            $redirectUrl = $store->getBaseUrl().'corporate/users';
            $result = $this->redirect->getRedirect($redirectUrl);
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i will try it.